# Python Input Validation with ipaddress Module

Tags: python-3.x, rest, ip-address

I'm currently creating a REST API application.  I'm having issues with input validation for IP addresses.  I have this working with just host IP addresses or network addresses. I want to combine both host and network into one function so I don't have to have two functions performing similar actions.

```
def add_ip_network():
   #IPv4 & v6 Address Handling.  Nothing but those formats can be entered.
  try:
    ip = ipaddress.ip_network(e1.get())
    nonsubnethostsList.append(ip)
    print("IP Network staged for deployment: %s" % (ip))
    e1.delete(0,END)
  except ValueError:
    print('Incorrect entry, please use IPv4 or IPv6 CIDR Formats')
    e1.delete(0,END)
    return 'Value'
  except TypeError:
    print('Incorrect entry, please use IPv4 or IPv6 CIDR Formats')
    e1.delete(0,END)
    return 'Type' 

def add_ip_host():
   #IPv4 & v6 Address Handling.  Nothing but those formats can be entered.
  try:
    ip = ipaddress.ip_ipaddress(e1.get())
    nonsubnethostsList.append(ip)
    print("IP Host staged for deployment: %s" % (ip))
    e1.delete(0,END)
  except ValueError:
    print('Incorrect entry, please use IPv4 or IPv6 CIDR Formats')
    e1.delete(0,END)
    return 'Value'
  except TypeError:
    print('Incorrect entry, please use IPv4 or IPv6 CIDR Formats')
    e1.delete(0,END)
    return 'Type'
```

These are the two functions that I have working.  When the try statement happens...if the ip variable doesn't equal the appropriate format of ipaddress.ipaddress or .ip_network it'll throw an error, because the module doesn't allow nonIPaddress inputs (which is what I want).

I want to combine these (like stated before) into one conditional statement.  Here is currently my UGLY setup which isn't working (it's within a Tkinter GUI).  The error handling works, the problem is it doesn't perform the if and elif statements after try self.ip = self.e1.get().

I'm trying to get them to enter in an IP address either in host format or in CIDR format...if one or the other is entered it performs the equivalent append to a list and let them know it's been added to the list.

Any suggestions to get this formatted correctly would be appreciated.

```
  def add_ip(self):
    self.hostiplist = []
    self.cidriplist = []
    try:
      if not self.e1.get():
        messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message='Ooops, Please enter an acceptible host or network IP Address.')
        self.e1.delete(0,END)
      elif self.e1.get() == " ":
        messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message='Ooops, Please enter an acceptible host or network IP Address.')
        self.e1.delete(0,END)
      else:
        try: 
          self.ip = self.e1.get() 
#Tried both directions of IPs with e1 in the begining or self.ip being in the front.
          if self.e1.get() == ipaddress.ip_address(self.ip):
            self.hostiplist.append(ip)
            print("IP Host staged for deployment: %s" % (ip))
            print("")
            self.e1.delete(0,END)
          elif self.ip == ipaddress.ip_network(self.e1.get()):
            self.cidriplist.append(ip)
            print("IP Network staged for deployment: %s" % (ip))
            print("")
            self.e1.delete(0,END)
          else:
            print("Didn't enter valid entry") # Placeholder for tests
        except:
          print('Nothing happened') # Placeholder for tests
    except ValueError:
      messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message='Ooops, Value Please enter an acceptible host or network IP Address.')
      self.e1.delete(0,END)
      return 'Value'    
    except TypeError:
      messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message='Ooops, Type Please enter an acceptible host or network IP Address.')
      self.e1.delete(0,END)
      return 'Type'
```

Any assistance would be great,

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. You can't run tkinter code via a REST interface.

Comment: I mentioned Tkinter just to mention it.  The code is meant to run behind the tkinter GUI.  My main question is I want inputs into these functions (hopefully combined) where they can only enter in IP Addresses in either CIDR or Host IP formats.  I have it working with the above two code examples, because if it's entered incorrectly it'll pass the Type or Value error...it doesn't seem to work within a combined setting.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I suggest you try rewriting it. It seems like the actual "question" part of your question is this statement: " the problem is it doesn't perform the if and elif statements after try self.ip = self.e1.get().". Is that correct? What do you mean by "doesn't perform the if statement"? Python won't just ignore statements randomly.  The best think you can do to get a good answer is to start with a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I wrote this in a hurry, as I was at work.  I'll rewrite this to be more thorough in my question.  To answer your question, after "try: self.ip = self.e1.get()" the code immediately executes: "except: print('Nothing happened') # Placeholder for tests".  With my new question that I write up later, I'll be asking why can't I get the same error handling results (or help me get the same results), that I got in the two separate functions above.

Comment: Perhaps you need to print out the exception rather than ignoring it. It is telling you important information. Exceptions and stack traces exist for a reason.

Comment: I'll take blame for the loss of information here, as my question and responses don't thoroughly explain everything.  Thanks for your suggestions.