# How ipaddress module in Python handles IPs

Tags: python, module, ip

I am asked to do an App to gives the total possible hosts for a subnet, Sadly I cannot use `ipaddress` module provided from Python so I need to write my own methods to check and validate entered data

My Code is like this:

```
def IP_Validation(chk_IP_vaild):
    if chk_IP_vaild.count(".") == 3 and all(isIP(i) for i in chk_IP_vaild.split(".")):
        return True
    return False
        
def isIP(IP_String):
    try:
        return str(int(IP_String)) == IP_String and 0 <= int(IP_String) <= 255
    except:
        return False

def Calc_Networks(IP_One , IP_Two):
    if IP_Validation(IP_One) and IP_Validation(IP_Two):
        print (IP_One,IP_Two)
    else:
        print ("There is an error")


Calc_Networks("172.11.254.1", "172.1.254.")
Calc_Networks("172.11.254.1", "172.1.254.0")
```

### Output

```
There is an error
172.11.254.1 172.1.254.0
```

but this only checks if entered IPs are IPv4, so I was googling and checking solutions over the Internet and I came across this:

```
import ipaddress
def calc_inclusive_subnet(ip1, ip2): #accepts 2 IP strings
    #make IP Address objects
    ip1_obj=ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip1)
    ip2_obj=ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip2)

    if ip1_obj<=ip2_obj:
        min_ip=ip1_obj
        max_ip=ip2_obj
    else:
        min_ip=ip2_obj
        max_ip=ip1_obj   
    distance = int(max_ip)-int(min_ip) #**
    return distance

print (calc_inclusive_subnet("192.168.1.0", "192.168.2.255"))
```

### Output

```
511
```

What I noticed that If I did a subtraction to two IPs declared with `ipaddress` module it does it right with no problem so I went to the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) in order to understand how this module handles IPs so I can use a similar method

Doing the subtraction using *code 1* it gives the following error:

```
def Calc_Networks(IP_One , IP_Two):
    if IP_Validation(IP_One) and IP_Validation(IP_Two):
        dis = int(IP_Two) - int(IP_One)
        return dis
```

The Output is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-9e53188ce6f1> in <module>
     16 
     17 
---> 18 print(Calc_Networks("172.11.254.1", "172.1.254.1"))
     19 Calc_Networks("172.11.254.1", "172.1.254.")

<ipython-input-154-9e53188ce6f1> in Calc_Networks(IP_One, IP_Two)
     12 def Calc_Networks(IP_One , IP_Two):
     13     if IP_Validation(IP_One) and IP_Validation(IP_Two):
---> 14         dis = int(IP_Two) - int(IP_One)
     15         return dis
     16 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '172.1.254.1'
```

also these posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461959/python-input-validation-with-ipaddress-module) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65334643/how-to-use-python-ipaddress-module) could not help me!

 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your `Calc_Networks` code didn't work but the `calc_inclusive_subnet` did is that in `calc_inclusive_subnet` an `ipaddress.IPv4Address` was passed to `int`, which has an `__int__` method, and gives you what you need. Your code, however, simply passes the string representation to `int`, which tries to parse the IP address as a normal int, which `"172.11.254.1"` isn't.

If you don't want to use `ipaddress` you can still implement a function to parse the IP address into a single integer:

```
def parse_ip_to_int(ip_address):
    octets = ip_address.split('.')
    return int.from_bytes(map(int, octets), 'big')
```

The above function splits `ip_address` into a list of strings, each string corresponding to one octet of the address (so for `"172.11.254.1"`, `["172", "11", "254", "1"]`). We then use `map` to convert those strings into `int`s. Finally we use the useful [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes), which allows us to convert that iterable of octets into one big integer. This could alternatively by achieved with a loop and bit shifting left by 8. The second argument of `int.from_bytes`, `'big'`, indicates that the most significant octet is the first one, which is how IPv4 addresses are encoded.

From here we can now correctly implement your `Calc_Networks` function. I have simplified it by using `abs` to ensure the distance we obtain is positive, rather than finding the minimum and maximum like in the original `calc_inclusive_subnet`.

```
def Calc_Networks(IP_One, IP_Two):
    if IP_Validation(IP_One) and IP_Validation(IP_Two):
        return abs(parse_ip_to_int(IP_One) - parse_ip_to_int(IP_Two))
```

Similar to your initial implementation, if the validation fails, then `None` is returned. A final note, although what I've presented does produce the same results as the `calc_inclusive_subnet` you've shown, all that function did was count the number of addresses from a starting address up to, but not including, an end address. Your desired behaviour may be different.